# vercel - how to return index.html on every route change?

Tags: typescript, webpack, vercel

i have a problem. i created a url shortener website with `typescript` and it is a single page website but the route can be changed. in this project i use `webpack` and for dev server i use `webpack-dev-server` and to return `index.html` for almost all routes, i wrote this code in `webpack.config.js`:

```
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    compress: true,
    proxy: {
      "/**": {
        target: "/index.html",
        secure: false,
        bypass: function (req, res, opt) {
          if (
            req.path.indexOf("/img/") !== -1 ||
            req.path.indexOf("/public/") !== -1
          ) {
            return "/";
          }

          if (req.path.indexOf("/build.css") !== -1) {
            return "/build.css";
          }

          if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
            return "/index.html";
          } else return;
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

now i want to enable this(returning `index.html` on every route change) for the vercel server of app.
at this time, when i change the route, i will get a 404 page. but i want to get `index.html`. i searched a lot to achieve what i want and i tested some ways but i couldnt do what i want.
i created a file called `vercel.json` at the root folder of my project and i tried `redirects`, `rewrites` and `routes`. i dont know, perhaps i used these properties wrong. so how can i do this? thanks for helping. i tried these configs and etc:

```
{
  "redirects": [{ "source": "/[^.]+", "destination": "/" }],
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/[^.]+", "destination": "/" }]
}


{
  "routes": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that I shouldn't have used `redirects` and `routes` property in `vercel.json` to achieve what I want. I should have used [`rewrites`](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/rewrites) instead. One other thing is that I used `rewrites` wrong. I should have used it like this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

According to the docs, this works "*because precedence is given to the filesystem prior to rewrites being applied*".

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed for my react SPA that uses no frameworks.